# Pandas compare each row to list

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe like the following

```
    Q1  Q2  Q3
0   'A' 'B' 'A'
1   'B' 'B' 'C'
```

and a list containing values I want to compare against

```
['B','B','A']
```

How do I obtain for each row how many column entries coincided with the respective list entry? So the output should be some form of

```
[2/3, 2/3]
```

Little code snippet for the above:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':['A','B'],'Q2':['B','B'],'Q3':['A','C']})
true_answers = ['B','B','A']
```

Comment: Why shall the second one be `1/3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare values by list (it has to be same length like number of columns) and get `mean` using [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) method:

```
s = df.eq(true_answers).mean(axis=1)
print (s)
0    0.666667
1    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

If want list use:

```
print (list(s))
[0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.eq(true_answers))
      Q1    Q2     Q3
0  False  True   True
1   True  True  False
```